# Why does Firefox tell me in my preference that my browser is being managed by my organization?

Tags: firefox, browser

I’m using 20.04 and in preference tab is where I found this.

Comment: Do you sign into Ubuntu via Active Directory credentials?

Comment: You can try updating firefox. It fixes the problem most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

your Linux distribution using organization policies to disable Firefox's builtin update checker, but nothing to worry about, it doesn't mean it's actually managed by your organization.

so It's Linux policy disabling the builtin update checker in Firefox so that it handles all updates through the package manager (apt/dpkg in Ubuntu).

Comment: That explains it clearly.Thanks

Comment: I doubt that. Firefox had always its builtin update checker disabled in Ubuntu and the updates were handled by apt, but this is provided by means of a Firefox extension installed by default with the bundled version. The message in question never appeared for me, so it seems not to be related to the way updates are handled. In Windows, such message is often caused by antivirus program being active. Maybe here @Simonb is also using some program that externally controls some settings in Firefox.

Comment: The standard package (Canonical) that comes with 20.04 does not have that message. It is a snap or a flatpak. See also my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Snap or a Flatpak. You will also notice that the option make Firefox my default browser is greyed out.

For more info please read the Wikipedia pages.
The Wikipedia page for snap:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(software).
The Wikipediapage for flatpak:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpak.

As of version 22.04 Firefox is installed as a snap.

If you want to install it as a .deb see:https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04.
You wil also notice that if you have a custom cursor in Ubuntu, it is not the same in the snap or flatpak. For a solution to this see [Adjust mousepointer in Firefox Flatpak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403342/adjust-mousepointer-in-firefox-flatpak)