# Firefox issue: Your browser is being managed by your organization

Tags: firefox

When I open Firefox, suddenly I cannot change some of the settings (such as site notifications or default browser) and I get a message "Your browser is being managed by your organization".
Then when I press it, I get a list: Policy Name     Policy Value
DisableAppUpdate    true, DontCheckDefaultBrowser   true

How can I regain the control and functionality of Firefox?

Note: I don't use Avast, nor AVG. Ubuntu version, 20.04. It's a personal computer.

Comment: Do you sign in with some sort of external authentication mechanism, such as LDAP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Firefox tell me in my preference that my browser is being managed by my organization?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302833/why-does-firefox-tell-me-in-my-preference-that-my-browser-is-being-managed-by-my)

Answer (score 2):

First open the settings (the 'hamburger', three stripes below eachother, on the right). Go to help, click on it, and go to `about Firefox` and click. Now you can see what version you are running. See screenshot of HomerSimpson. You probably run the flatpak.
 Open a new tab and type `about:config`. Search for `Policy Name Policy Value DisableAppUpdate`. In my case it didn't excist (flatpak). So I made it by clicking on the `+` and changed the value from `false` to `true` by clicking on the double arrows.
Then I searched for `DefaultBrowser` and changed the two lines true to false and false to true.(see screenshots, changes are bold)[[image][image].
If you want more freedom download the `Firefox Webbrowser`. Read the discription. The upper one is the flatpak! [image], while the one below that is the Ubuntu Canonical version (size=smaller)[image]

Comment: I would not change the values of the app update though, as this is a flatpak.

Comment: Thanks for the about:config details. I had forgotten about those for a minute. ;) 
btw I am not running flatpak or snap and I have this issue. I am however running POP OS's version of Ubuntu, which may be the reason. I can't find anything related to this and Pop right now, but thanks to this, I don't need to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is due to it being a `snap`- or `flatpak`-version of `Firefox`.[image]
[image].
They have different icons as well. [image]
[image]

Comment: Hello. Your answer is totally off base and has no basis for such an answer.

Comment: @ David My Flatpak-version has the same issue, while my Ubuntu-version does not! Hence my answer. See screenshots and please remove downvote.

Comment: There is no such thing as a Ubuntu version. There is from the Ubuntu Software which is the same as the apt version, snap and flatpak.

Comment: By the ubuntu-version I ment the version for Ubuntu Canonical. But take a look at the screenshots and look at the differences. Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu Canonical 1.0 is called Firefox Webbrowser. The flatpak is just called Firefox. They are different, they are not the same. Install them yourself, and look in ```about: config```. Different.(big dot)

Comment: @David They are not the same. The flatpak has way less options. You downvoted the answer? HomerSimpson is right! 1 upvote.