24.04 Noble snap Firefox - I can edit Settings/General/fake-favicon-uri, but it doesn't save (same using about:config)
I tried to make the change manually in both Settings and about:config.
Change was from "Use System Handler" to /home/[USER]/.mozilla/firefox/[XXX].default-release/favicons.sqlite
At the top of the Settings page is the line "Your browser is being managed by your organization".
Didn't get any errors, but the change was not saved in either environment.
Instead, it retained value of Use System Handler.

Solution is to switch to the APT version of Firefox https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466

also related https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1264369 Basically the quoted message is nothing to worry about. There's a good deal of positive  comment about the benefits of replacing the Snap version with the .deb version or indeed the Flatpak one (which I have done)

This question is similar to: How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can be caused by security software installed. Hower, take a look at this answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400559/firefox-issue-your-browser-is-being-managed-by-your-organization
