# Adjust mousepointer in Firefox Flatpak

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, canonical, flatpak, mouse-pointer

How do I get the same mousepointer in `Firefox` (Flatpak) as in my `Kubuntu 20.04.2` OS. The one in `Firefox (Flatpak)` is a little black pointer, while in `Firefox (Canonical)` it is the same as in my OS. (see pictures for the difference) [image: flatpak mousepointer] and 
[image: canonical mousepointer]
The `flatpak` is on the left, `Canonical` on the right. In `about:config` I searched for `mouse`, `pointer` and `arrow`, compared them and found no differences (arrow came up with nothing). Does anyone have an idea what to search for in `about:config`? 
The reason I got the `flatpak` is that when I upgrade the `Canonical FF` it goes crazy. Only visible thing is the titlebar, the rest is seethrough. So as long as I wait for Kubuntu 22.04, I will use the `flatpak`. 
The theme I made for `Firefox` is downloadable for free, so if you like these dutch trains, go ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very useful workaround for cursor issues has been posted on the forums [over at Linux Mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1980046&sid=232ac864b67fa034ed14e372b29d95f8#p1980046). It involves giving the flatpak sandbox of the application access to the cursor themes:

```
flatpak --user override --filesystem=/home/$USER/.icons/:ro
flatpak --user override --filesystem=/usr/share/icons/:ro
```

It "weakens" the sandbox a little bit, but I would assume that the extra security risks here are very minimal.

Comment: I put the commands in the terminal, restarted the flatpak Firefox and I have my mousepointer! Great! Thank you so much.