# Firefox "Your browser is being managed by your organization."

Tags: firefox

What is this thing in Firefox settings "Your browser is being managed by your organization." ? All the answers I have so far found in AskUbuntu seem to not be to the point.

Comment: Where in the firefox settings do you see this?  Are you on a system that is managed by, say, an Active Directory environment or some kind of locked-down controls on your system?  What Ubuntu are you using?  (I see this in Windows installs where GPO controls your Firefox bits, but not often in Linux)

Answer (score 1):

It is a `Snap` or a `Flatpak`. You will also notice that the option `make Firefox my default browser` is greyed out. 
For more info please read the Wikipedia pages.
The Wikipedia page for snap:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(software).
 The Wikipediapage for flatpak:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpak. 
As of version 22.04 Firefox is installed as a snap.
If you want to install it as a .deb see:https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04.
You will also notice that, if you use a custom cursor in Ubuntu, it will not be the same in your snap or flatpak. To solve this see [Adjust mousepointer in Firefox Flatpak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403342/adjust-mousepointer-in-firefox-flatpak).

Comment: Es, can you explain your answer? What are Snap and Flatpack?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for snap:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(software). The Wikipediapage for flatpak:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpak. Please read them. (edited this in my answer too.) They work in a kind of container environment, unlike the normal .deb packages.

Comment: @raj. Thanks for the edit ( although I wanted my son to do that so he would get some points ).