# Custom cursor not appearing over applications (fixed)

Tags: cursor

Edit: This problem has been fixed. It involved using a terminal command to give flatpak apps a tiny bit less security restrictions so custom cursors could appear over it. The command is in the comments

Recently I've been using Ubuntu for casual stuff and today I've noticed the link cursor looks.. weird. It isn't the Yaru/custom cursor and I keep getting bothered by it unfortunately. Is there a way to revert this? This happens on Discord and Spotify so far and both of them are flatpak installs.

This is how the cursor looks like in apps like Discord and Spotify. It looks hard to see compared to the Yaru selection icon:

[image]

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403342/adjust-mousepointer-in-firefox-flatpak/1403352#1403352

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adjust mousepointer in Firefox Flatpak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403342/adjust-mousepointer-in-firefox-flatpak)